# html2pdf library returning blank fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, html2canvas

I am using [this](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf) client side HTML to PDF conversion library. The PDF turned out to be 14 pages long. However at around 6 or 7 pages the background colors are completely gone even though the text is still there.

This is my code

```
var element = document.getElementById('element-to-print');
  var opt = {
  margin:       0,
  filename:     'myfile.pdf',
  image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
  html2canvas:  { dpi: 300, letterRendering: true},
  jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
};
html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).save();
```

Comment: Could you use the browser's default 'save as PDF' option? It would require no library or integration, you can define your styles in a print stylesheet.

Comment: I am sending the converted PDF back to the server where I send it via email. Browser does not allow me to store the PDF in a viariable